# Laravel - How to Pass Parameter to return redirect

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have:

```
public function manager_employee_goal_list($id)
{
    $goal = AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($id);
    $goaldetails = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $id)->get();

    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list')
        ->with('goal', $goal)
        ->with('goaldetails', $goaldetails);       
} 

public function manager_employee_goal_approve(Request $request, $id)
{
    $goal = AppraisalGoal::find($id);
    $goal->is_approved = 3;
    $goal->line_manager_comment = $request->line_manager_comment;
    $goal->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Goal is approved');

    return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list');        
}
```

view : manager_employee_goal_list

```
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#approve{{ $goal->id }}" data-original-title="Approve">
   Approve
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="approve{{ $goal->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_approve',['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Approve Goal
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Comment</label>
                        <textarea rows="2" name="line_manager_comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment here" value="{{old('line_manager_comment')}}" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required"></textarea> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Approve Goal</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

route/web.php

```
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal_list/{id?}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal_list')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list');
Route::post('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal_approve/{id?}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal_approve')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_approve');
```

When I submit on the modal form, it saves but couldn't redirect to:

> return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list');

It displays this error

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController::manager_employee_goal_list(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: I think you could`return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list', $goal->id);`

Comment: there's another concern, which you put your route is `{id?}`, which mean it is optional for id, but in your function it is compulsory, suggest to use `public function manager_employee_goal_list($id = null)` or `Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal_list/{id}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsC...`

Comment: Yes, and if you want optional parameter dont use findOrFail and the folliwing logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`manager_employee_goal_list` method expects an ID, all you have to do is to pass that ID, like so:

```
return redirect()->route(
        'appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list',
        ['id' => $id]
);
```

Also I suggest you to either remove question mark after `id` in your defined route, or update arguments from your method by making them nullable

```
public function manager_employee_goal_list($id = null)
```

and of course you have to adjust code too